# error on compiling matconvnet

Tags: c++, matlab, error-handling, vlfeat, matconvnet

After following [these commands](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/quick/) to compile matconvnet.
when I run `run matlab/vl_compilenn` in matlab, I receive the following error:

```
Error using vl_compilenn>check_clpath (line 577)
Unable to find cl.exe

Error in vl_compilenn (line 400)
    check_clpath(); % check whether cl.exe in path

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Error is related to cl.exe which seems like Visual C++ compiler. I have Windows updated with bunch of 'Microsoft Visual c++ redistribuibile' already installed.

I have Matlab 2016a on Windows 7

Comment: Maybe I need to install Visual studio?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.

Comment: after installing Visual Studio and restarting, still get the same error.

Comment: And of course you will also need to ensure that the directory containing `cl.exe` is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Also make sure that you run `mex -setup` first - that actually does search for the VisualStudio installation...

Comment: The solution is given in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226354/matconvnet-error-cl-exe-not-found)